# Power BI Embedded - .net 6

Tags: c#, powerbi, .net-6.0, azure-service-principal

We are in the process of upgrading our web application to .net 6 and Power BI embedded is an issue.  We had this previously working with a master username / password but this is no longer supported.

I've followed the steps outlined here to create app registration and service principal.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-customer-app

As well as created something similar to this source code:
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/.NET%20Core/Embed%20for%20your%20customers

I am able to authenticate and receive an access token but when I use the power bi client to get groups or reports it always returns 0 records.   I am not receiving any errors.  Am I missing a setting in Power BI?  The security group we created has access to the workspaces.

Code to authenticate - Working without error

```
 AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;

        // Create a confidential client to authorize the app with the AAD app
        IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(authorityUrl)
            .Build();
        // Make a client call if Access token is not available in cache
        authenticationResult = clientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(scopeBase).ExecuteAsync().Result;

        return authenticationResult;
```

Getting Access Token and creating power bi client

```
var authenticationResult = GetAuthenticationResult(clientId, clientSecret, scopeBase, authorityUrl);

        if (authenticationResult != null)
        {
            var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");
            var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(apiUrl), tokenCredentials);

            client.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(200);
            client.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ActivityId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

            return client;
        }

        return null;
```

Then when I try to get groups, it returns 0 records

```
var workspaces = (await client.Groups.GetGroupsAsync()).Value;
```

When I try to get reports it shows forbidden on the first call and unauthenticated on the 2nd call.  What permissions am I missing?

```
var reports = (await client.Reports.GetReportsAsync()).Value;
var report = (await client.Reports.GetReportsInGroupAsync(new Guid(powerBiWorkspace.WorkspaceId))).Value;
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `GetGroupsAsync` returns the list of workspaces, in which the "current user" is a member. When using master user, it will return the list of workspaces, where this user is a member. Similarly, when using service principal, it will return the list of workspaces, where this service principal is a member. Obviously, you didn't made it a member to any workspace. The alternative is to use the admin API by calling [GetGroupsAsAdminAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powerbi.api.groupsoperationsextensions.getgroupsasadminasync?view=azure-dotnet) method.

Comment: My security group that is part of the service principal is a member of the workspaces I need for power bi embedded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that I did not have the service principal assigned to the new security group.  Once that was done, I was able to successfully use the API calls.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment in Postman and got the same error as below:***

```json
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups
```

[image]

The **`401`** error usually occurs if the required permissions is missing to perform the action.

**To resolve the error, check the below:**

I created the Azure AD Application and added API permissions:

Make sure to grant admin consent for
**`Workspace.ReadWrite.All`** permission.

[image]

I created a **security group and added the Service Principal** as a member like below:

[image]

In PowerBi Admin Portal, Enable  **`Allow service principals to use read-only admin APIs`**  added the security group:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

To fetch the groups try **calling API as Admin** like below:

```json
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups?$top=100
```

[image]

I agree with @Andrey Nikolov, try using **`GetGroupsAsAdminAsync`** to fetch the groups like below:

```cs
public static 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.Models.Groups> 
GetGroupsAsAdminAsync (this Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.IGroupsOperations 
operations, int top, string expand = default, string filter = default, 
int? skip = default, System.Threading.CancellationToken 
cancellationToken = default);
```